# How to resize the axes of an graph on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I need ideas to **resize my axes** to have a much more airy graph to better visualize and calculate the gain between the different curves.

I used the code : `axis([0 6 1e-3 1e0])` or `xlim([0 6]); ylim([1e-3 1e0])`

[image]

I would like to have for example my curve with: `xlim([0:0.2:6])` (just the idea, otherwise it's wrong on matlab).

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Logarithmic Plot:

To create the axes the function `xticks()` and `yticks()` can be used to set the intervals, start and endpoints. `xticks()` and `yticks()` essentially take vectors that define all the ticks on the scales/axes. Just in case you'd like to also edit the interval along the y-axis. This vector can be created by raising each element in the vector `(-3,1:0)` to be an exponent with a base of 10. Finally, setting `gca` (the current axis) to logarithmic will allow the vertical spacing between the ticks to be evenly distributed.

[image: Logarithmic Plot]

```
axis([0 6 1e-3 1e0]);

Start = 0; Interval = 0.2; End = 6;
X_Vector = (Start: Interval: End);
xticks(X_Vector);

Y_Vector = 10.^(-3: 1: 0);
yticks(Y_Vector);
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
title("Logarithmic Plot");
grid;
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you @MichaelTr7 for the idea. It worked well.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want, you need more XTicks in the x limits mentioned. After you plot just:

```
set(gca,'XTick',0:0.2:6)
```

another way is to write:

```
h=plot(.... whatever you plot... 
h.XTick=0:0.2:6
```